# why after animation and Visibility: Gone -> Visibility: Visible, view is not responsive

Tags: xml, android-xml

I'm making an animation that makes my view go to the bottom. So that it cannot be clicked by calling setOnClickListener set after the animation Visibility: Gone. But after appearing through the animation and Visibility: Visible, it stopped responding to clicks, what should I do?